# I need to use rewrite nginx matching location with arg key

Tags: nginx

I am using one URL for different purposes:

1. /path/items : returns a list of items
2. /path/items?id=XXX : redirects to URL */path/items/item?id=XXX*

EDIT: Added solution based on Tero's input

I've tried that rule in my nginx conf file:

```
location ~ / {
    rewrite '^/path/items\?id=([0-9]*)$' /items/item?id=$1? break;
}
```

When I access the page /path/items?id=XXX, I get the following log:

> 2016/08/25 14:08:53 [notice] 22903#0: *1 "^/path/items\?id=([0-9]*)$"
>   does not match "/path/items", client: XXX, server: local.xxx.ins,
>   request: "GET /path/items?id=32442305 HTTP/1.1", host: "local.xxx.ins"

I understand from that log that nginx remove the args before doing the match. but I cannot find out how to get a match including the args.

I came up with a solution realy close to Tero's one.

```
location ~ /(path1|path2|path3) {
    if ($arg_id) {
        rewrite ^ $uri/item break;
     }
     proxy_pass http://local.xxx.ins:8080;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$args ~ id=(.+)` test in the `if` statement, you should be able to simply use `$arg_id`. It is a bit faster, since the regex engine isn't used.

Comment: I overlooked it, thanks so much for the feedback again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot process query strings within `rewrite` directives. You can only process URI there.

You can try this configuration:

```
location /path/items {
    if ($arg_item) {
        rewrite ^ /items/item break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

The `location /path/items` restricts this behavior only to URIs that have `/path/items` prefix. We test if a query argument `item` is defined in the HTTP request. If it is, we rewrite the URI. Otherwise we just try the URIs given by the client.

You might need modification of the `try_files` directive depending on how the items list is made. You might also need a `root` directive if it is not defined in the `server` level.

Comment: I came up with a pretty close solution yesterday, I'll edit my question using a mix of your solution and mine, thanks for your time !

Comment: you don't need to add the $args in rewrite as the arguments are automatically passed on.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to have the /location be handled by a CGI, or PHP script (see here for [nginx and php](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)) and the have them inspect the QUERY_STRING and issue back a [location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header

Comment: Thank you for your time, nevertheless, I cannot use CGI here, I need to use plain NGINX

Comment: You may be able to hack up something by using $args and the if directive https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/